# Performing an HTTP POST without encoding a particular parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-request

I'm trying to talk to an undocumented third-party API using Node and the request module.

The following code generates the request:

```
request.post(
        {
            url: url,
            headers: MY_HEADERS_HERE,
            followAllRedirects: true,
            json: true,
            form: form,
            jar: this.jar,
            gzip: true
        })
```

I'm sending the POST request to a URL with a GET paramater, let's say `http://example.com/path?action=/some/action`

Because of some quirks in the API, the GET paramater and its value also need to be present in the form, unencoded, so the proper body of the POST request should be something like:

`parameter1=somedata&parameter2=somedata&action=/some/action`

However, since the requests module encodes all form parameters, the contents of the body are:

`parameter1=somedata&parameter2=somedata&action=%2Fsome%Faction`

Is there some way to disable form URL encoding in the requests module? The only thing I can think of right now is to write a method that converts the form object into a query string manually.

Thank you

Tobias Timpe

Answer (score 0):

You could use `decodeURIComponent(url)` to decode your parameters. Maybe you should split your url instead using it for the whole url.

```
request.post(
{
   url: 'http://example.com/path?' +
        'action=' + decodeURIComponent(actionparam),
   headers: MY_HEADERS_HERE,
   followAllRedirects: true,
   json: true,
   form: form,
   jar: this.jar,
   gzip: true
```

})

Comment: My problem is not the parameter in the URL but rather the one in the request body.